# How to color the CSS loader?

Tags: html, css, preloader

I have working code for a CSS preloader at [CSS preloader sample](https://js.do/sun21170/css-issue-with-child-widths)

I would like the animated preloader to be colored. I tried adding the style `color: red !important;` to various styles to the CSS class `lds-ripple`, but it did nothing.
A colored preloader would look more impressive in my view.

How would I make the CSS preloader show with colored rings?

the same code from working sample is also pasted below.

```
<button id="btnShow" onclick="showLoader()">Show Loader</button>
<div id="loader">
<div class="lds-ripple"><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>

<style>
#loader {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:green solid 1 px;
  opacity:0.9;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
 }
.lds-ripple {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.lds-ripple div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
 }
.lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
@keyframes lds-ripple {
  0% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.9% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


</style>
<script>
function showLoader() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "flex";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#fff` in the line marked below can be changed to set the loader's color.

```css
.lds-ripple div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid #fff; /* edit this line */
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
}
```

For example:

```js
function showLoader() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "flex";
}
showLoader();
```

```css
#loader {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:green solid 1 px;
  opacity:0.9;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
 }
.lds-ripple {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.lds-ripple div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid red;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
 }
.lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
@keyframes lds-ripple {
  0% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  4.9% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
<div class="lds-ripple"><div></div><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ouroborus, is it also possible to have rings of different colors expand like a green ring which becomes a red ring as it expands and then the next expanded ring becomes blue?

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen, I tried your suggestion but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I apologize, let me test something.

Comment: @Sunil I added correct animation keyframes in my answer. Sorry for inconvenience. Try running the code snippet in it.

Comment: Yep! By the way I really think the single color ones already look good :) But do as you please :3

Answer (score 1):

### For changing color animation:

```css
@keyframes lds-ripple {
  0% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: red;
  }
  4.9% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: red;
  }
  5% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    border-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `div`s inside the `lds-ripple` have no dimension into it. So the `color` property won't have any effect. However, the `border-color` will still work. So you can replace the default `#fff` color with something like red. For example:

```css
.lds-ripple div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid red; /* HERE */
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
}
```

```js
function showLoader() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "flex";
}
```

```css
#loader {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: green solid 1 px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.lds-ripple {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.lds-ripple div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid red; /* HERE */
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ripple 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
}

.lds-ripple div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

@keyframes lds-ripple {
  0% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: red;
  }
  4.9% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: red;
  }
  5% {
    top: 36px;
    left: 36px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    border-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    opacity: 0;
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btnShow" onclick="showLoader()">Show Loader</button>
<div id="loader">
  <div class="lds-ripple">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was such a silly thing that I missed.